# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mapsforge

I am struggling to run a basic Mapsforge application. I have added all its required jar files to project and gradle. But i am not able to run application. Getting following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/mapsforge/map/reader/Way.class
```

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test.mapsforge"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/mapsforge-core-0.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mapsforge-map-0.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mapsforge-map-android-0.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mapsforge-map-awt-0.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/SwingMapViewer-0.5.1.jar')
}
```

Folder structure

[image: Folder structure]

I have tried adding `multiDexEnabled true` in gradle config but didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to multidex?  The decencies seem somewhat scarce and unless they are packed with methods I don't see how you would get past the 65k method limit.  I also don't see a dependency for compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'  Please check https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html or try not using ultidex.   You also may need to extend MultiDexApplication instead of a regular Application.  I think your issue is really a duplicate dependency and not aa dex limit.  have you tried gradle :app:dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I face same error too. when I delete swing map viewer every thing work fine even without using multiDexEnabled true